# Connecting to Postgres from Remote Network

Tags: postgresql

Unable to get data from Postgres from remote network.  We have a Postgres DB setup for our MItel System and users from different vlans cannot get data.  They can connect to the DB successfully but getting "no records found" when connected. The users that are connect to the same vlan as the DB can connect fine and get all the data (call History) but users from a branch office cannot receive data.

What I have setup in the pg_hba.conf file is:

```
host   all    all    10.0.0.0/24   trust  (I've tried md5 as well)
host   all    all    172.0.0.0/24  trust
```

In the Postgressql.conf I have:

```
Listen_addresses = '*'
```

All users are using the same database username and password.

Comment: What do you mean by the remote users can connect to the DB, but get a "no records found".  That doesn't make any sense really.  If they can connect and have privileges it seems like they should be able to query.  Do you have a firewall issue, something like that ?

Comment: There are approx 20 users that connect.  Users on 10.0.0.0 can connect and get data just fine.  users on network 172.0.0.0 can connect to the database (with MD5 or TRUST set) but get no data from the database.

Comment: The Mitel software has a Call history option where we can setup the username, password, database name, and Server name with a TEST CONNECTION button.  All those are set and the results are SUCCESSFUL.  But NO data is showing in the Call History.  Says No Records Fount.   There is no firewall issues at all.

Comment: Best guess is the users from 10.0.0.0 are not connecting to the same database as the other users. I'm going to say it has same name but different port number. Verify that all the connection settings are the same for both sets of users. Also look at Postgres log for database you know has data and look for connections. This may require enabling `log_connections` and `log_disconnections`, see here [What to log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT).

Comment: I will give that a shot.  All users are connecting through the Mmitel software with these values  DB username - ipconsoleattendant, DB user password - ######, DB Server Name - MICC01. adn DB Name - IP_Console.   All users have those setup and teh Mitel software had the Username and DB name hard set (meaning can't change it)  all users are the same though.

Comment: You are not showing the `port` number and that is the important part in this equation. Also add the connection information as update to your question so folks don't have to work through the comments to get relevant data.

Comment: The port setting in the postgressql.conf file is set to...port = 5432

Comment: No, the `port` number in the client connection setting.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what i needed to put in the pg_hba.conf file.  The line needed to read
host   all    all  0.0.0.0/0    md5

Not quite sure why the network address or subnet didn't work but they didn't.  For whatever reason that line worked and all data is flowing.  Thanks